# Concatenate two fields in GridView (one with an anonymous function)

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have a GridView

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [   
            'team2.name',    
            [
                'header' => 'Players name',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value'=>function ($model) {
                    return implode('', ArrayHelper::getColumn($model->playerLastnames, 'lastname'));
                },
            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

This works and I have team's name in first column and player's name in second. 
The question is how to make one column in that format: 
*team's name(player's name)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming that the team name is in the models as `your_team_name` 
you could use an anonymous function for concatenete both

```
  <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [   

            [
                'header' => 'Team and Players name',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value'=>function ($model) {
                    return $model->your_team_name  . ' ' . implode('', ArrayHelper::getColumn($model->playerLastnames, 'lastname'));
                },
            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need.